# getting highest smallest floats values from mixed list with inf in list

Tags: python, list, inf

list float values & inf repeat many times inside list

**the mission is** extract the highest float value & smallest float value
**Noting that :** there are inf appears in the list

```
**my code :**
```

```
list  = (inf , inf , inf , inf , 0.9 , 0.5 , 2.5 , 3.5 , 4.9 , 9.9 , 0.2)


def get_highest_lowest():
    lowest = 0
    highest = 0


    for i in list:
        if i >= 0 and i != float('inf'):

            # get lowest value
            if lowest > i:
                lowest = i
                

            # get highest value
            if highest < i:
                highest = i
                

        

    return [highest , lowest]
```

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried running your code? Whats the output of the code you ran?

Comment: the output only show this [Finished in 62ms]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to set initial `lowest` as `np.inf`

```
import numpy as np
lst  = (np.inf , np.inf , np.inf , np.inf , 0.9 , 0.5 , 2.5 , 3.5 , 4.9 , 9.9 , 0.2)


def get_highest_lowest():
    lowest = np.inf
    highest = -np.inf


    for i in lst:
        if i >= 0 and i != float('inf'):

            # get lowest value
            if lowest > i:
                lowest = i
                

            # get highest value
            if highest < i:
                highest = i
                

        

    return [highest , lowest]

get_highest_lowest()
>>> [9.9, 0.2]
```

Comment: can i use inf = float('inf')
without calling numpy

Comment: Of course you can do it that way